# How to create multiple PlantUML diagrams from a python script?

Tags: python, diagram, flowchart, plantuml

## Scenario

Most instructions suggest you can generate PlantUML diagrams with python using: `python -m plantuml example_diagram.txt`. I wanted to create a python script that generates multiple PlantUML diagrams when it is created, such that I can instantly update a complete set of diagrams, without having to run multiple commands.

## Example Files

The following files are used to generate the PlantUML graphs:

1. `example_flow.txt` with content:

```
' http://tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html#orgheadline19
' http://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html

' Indicate the direction of the flowchart
left to right direction

' Give a block the variable name 'first' and define starting point as (*)
(*) --> "The first block" as first

first --> "A" as A
' Give the block a variable name s.t. you can just use its variable name in the next blocks
  --> "D" as D
first --> "B" as B
  --> D
first --> "C" as C
  --> D
  
' Define end point as (*)  
D --> (*)
```

2. `Graphviz_example.txt` with content:

```
' http://tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html#orgheadline19
' http://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html

digraph summary{
    // initialize the variable blocks
    start [label="Start with a Node"]
    next [label="Choose your shape", shape=box]
    warning [label="Don't go overboard", color=Blue, fontcolor=Red,fontsize=24,style=filled, fillcolor=green,shape=octagon]
    end [label="Draw your graph!", shape=box, style=filled, fillcolor=yellow]

    // Indicate the direction of the flowchart
    rankdir=LR; // Rank direction left to right
    
    // Create the connections
    start->next
    start->warning 
    next->end [label="Getting Better...", fontcolor=darkblue]

}
```

## Question

How can I create these diagrams from a single python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Generate for 2 files in the same directory

Create a python file named `create_diagrams.py` with content:

```
from plantuml import PlantUML
from os.path import abspath

# create a server object to call for your computations
server = PlantUML(url='http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/img/',
                          basic_auth={},
                          form_auth={}, http_opts={}, request_opts={})

# Send and compile your diagram files to/with the PlantUML server
server.processes_file(abspath('./example_flow.txt'))
server.processes_file(abspath('./Graphviz_example.txt'))
```

And run it, for example in anaconda with python 3.6 with command: `python create_diagrams.py`.

## Generate for all files in directory

One can also generate the diagrams for all `.txt` files in a directory named `Diagrams` with:

```
from plantuml import PlantUML
import os
from os.path import abspath

server = PlantUML(url='http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/img/',
                          basic_auth={},
                          form_auth={}, http_opts={}, request_opts={})


# create subfolder name
diagram_dir = "./Diagrams"

# loop through all .txt files in the subfolder
for file in os.listdir(diagram_dir):
  filename = os.fsdecode(file)
  if filename.endswith(".txt"):
    # Call the PlantUML server on the .txt file
    server.processes_file(abspath(f'./Diagrams/{filename}'))
```

## Notes

This implementation requires an active internet connection because your asking the PlantUML server to do the graph generation for you. To compile locally, you can also download the `.jar` file of the PlantUML software and call that from python to do your computation. A more detailed example of this is given in [the question of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303335/ipython-notebook-plantuml-extension).